What stage of boot is asking for my password?
I just finished this guide on (almost) full disk encryption. So now my root directory and /boot directory are both encrypted, and GRUB is password-protected. /boot/efi is still unencrypted. I haven't done section 4 of the guide yet (which will auto-complete password prompts 2 and 3 below once finished)
Times where I typed my password are marked with red. I enter my password here (this first prompt is the one I have a question about)

and then select Ubuntu in GRUB:

and then again later in the boot process I am prompted to unlock each partition.

and after that Ubuntu boots and prints more output: (this is a representative sample but far from all of the output)


and then I get the login screen.
Prompts 1, 2, and 3 are set up to be the same password (I don't know if they're all checking against the same resource for the hash, but at the least, the same input unlocks each one). The GRUB password is different and it is only asked for if I attempt to change GRUB settings (so, it is not prompt 1). I'm pretty sure prompts 2 and 3 are the cryptoLUKS system to unlock each partition.

So what is prompt 1? When I enter my password, what program is handling it? Is that part
of cryptoLUKS? GRUB? Something lower-level?
And what exactly am I unlocking? I have two encrypted partitions but three times I enter a password, so where does that odd prompt out go?

Thank you very much!

hd0 is Grub's syntax for hard disks. Prompt 1 is Grub asking for the passphrase to decrypt the encryption key for the encrypted partition containing /boot.
Prompts 2 and 3 are from Linux. The cryptsetup utility (at this point, the copy of it in the initramfs) is asking for the passphrase to decrypt the encryption key for the encrypted partition containing the root directory (prompt 2), then the same for /boot (prompt 3). The encryption at that point is managed inside the Linux kernel; cryptsetup is the utility that interacts with the user and relays the user's wishes to the kernel.
Passing information from Grub to the kernel without exposing it in plain text is not completely straightforward, which is why that guide has you do more work in section 4.

But isn't grub itself in /boot/grub? In which case, wouldn't that need to be decrypted first before grub can even be launched? Or is that just where it ends up once Linux has been booted and the systems loaded? (or should I ask a new question and stop making a nuisance of myself?)

@terdon The part of Grub that knows how to read /boot (including decryption if that's necessary) is on the EFI partition.

Ah! Gotcha, and /boot/grub just has the configuration stuff. Makes sense, thanks.

@terdon you're not being a nuisance! In my understanding, GRUB isn't stored in /boot/grub, but after booting is finished, a bridge is constructed between the partition where GRUB is and the partition where the root filesystem is stored. On the root filesystem's side, this bridge touches down at /boot/grub. (and the process of building this metaphorical bridge is called mounting). So the root filesystem's /boot/grub has nothing in it, but then after boot there is a bridge to some files in a different place. What's the difference between actually having the files in that dir and (1/2)

(2/2) having a bridge to files in some foreign location in that dir? To most programs, apparently none at all! They can't tell, the difference is abstracted away, the two look identical to mere common programs. I would appreciate it someone could double-check this for correctness though!

Ah, typo - in my first comment, replace GRUB with "GRUB's configuration options". GRUB itself is on the EFI partition.

@Gilles Ok! Thank you! So then, prompt 1 and 3 do the same thing - they decrypt /boot. But why does /boot have to be unencrypted twice? I understand that's there's currently no good way to pass info from GRUB to the kernel, but it seems as if that isn't necessary. /boot is already unencrypted. Prompt 1 can decrypt it, then leave it in plaintext for anyone else to read. So when Prompt 3 comes up, it shouldn't need to decrypt /boot, because /boot is already in plaintext.

Unless..
A) /boot gets re-encrypted somewhere between Prompt 1 and 3?  Like Prompt 1 reverts its changes before passing control to someone else? or..... B) /boot has two layers of encryption? cryptoLUKS encrypts the partition, then GRUB encrypts that already-encrypted partition? (or maybe it encrypts the set of both partitions?)
Are either of these close to correct? Thank you for all the help!
I'll be publishing a separate question about the security implications of this.

@SuperDialga Grub reads the kernel and initramfs from /boot. Then the main operating system mounts /boot. The content of /boot isn't needed for day-to-day operation, but it's needed whenver the kernel or grub is upgraded. By the way, note that if you're going to encrypt /boot, it doesn't need to be separate from the root partition. (Nowadays the main reason to separate /boot is to encrypt the root partition without the hassle of encrypting the bootloader, which is pretty much useless.)
